# Перемещение уже созданного файла(фотографии) на рабочий стол

Tags: java, файлы

Делаю игру, придумал вознаградить игрока за прохождение игры аватаркой(ну что то вроде обычной фотографии с .png). Аватарку я положил в корневую. Вопрос, могу ли я переместить эту аватарку на рабочий стол? Если да то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myFile.renameTo(new File("/the/new/place/newName.file"));` - [`File.renameTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) не только переименовывает файл, но и может переместить его. Дока:

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.

Автоперевод:

> Переименовывает файл, обозначенный этим абстрактным путем.
>
> Многие аспекты поведения этого метода зависят от платформы: операция
>   переименования может не переносить файл из одной файловой системы в
>   другую, она может быть не атомарной, и может не получиться, если файл
>   с конечный абстрактный путь уже существует. Всегда нужно проверить
>   возвращаемое значение, чтобы убедиться, что операция переименования
>   прошла успешно.

[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4645271/7150209)